# The RATS sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic

Your task is to generate the nth term of the RATS sequence, where n is the input. The RATS sequence is also known as the Reverse Add Then Sort sequence. This sequence can also be found here: http://oeis.org/A004000.

test cases:

```
0 > 1
1 > 2
2 > 4
3 > 8
4 > 16
5 > 77
6 > 145
7 > 668
```

For example, the output for 5 is 77 because 16 + 61 = 77. After this the 77 is sorted.

Shortest submission wins. This is my first challenge so i hope this is not a duplicate or something.

Comment: Does the input have to be an Integer or could it also be a string?

Comment: @DenkerAffe do you mean a number in the form of a string?

Comment: @justaprogrammer Yea, so I can get "123" instead of 123 as Integer. Would mayve save some bytes.

Comment: @DenkerAffe sure, if that works best

Comment: isn't 77+77=154? Or have I missed something? EDIT: Oh, yes, I forgot to sort.

Comment: @DenhamCoote I think you meant "oh rat***s***, I forgot to sort!"

Answer (score 12):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 11 <s>12</s> bytes

```
1i"tVPU+VSU
```

Input is a *string* (with single quotes) representing an integer in *unary*. String input is allowed by the challenge, and unary [is a valid format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5344/36398).

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MWkidFZQVStWU1U&input=JzExMTExMTEn)

#### Explanation

```
1      % push number 1 to the stack
i      % input. Will be a string of "n" ones 
"      % for loop: repeat n times (consumes string)
  t    %   duplicate
  V    %   convert to string
  P    %   reverse
  U    %   convert to number
  +    %   add
  V    %   convert to string
  S    %   sort
  U    %   convert to number
       % loop is implicitly ended
       % stack content is implicitly displayed
```

Comment: I don't know which scares/perplexes me more, MATL or Jelly... +1

Answer (score 10):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Code:

```
$FDR+{
```

Explanation:

```
$       # Push 1 and input
 F      # For N in range(0, input)
  D     # Duplicate top of the stack
   R    # Reverse top of the stack
    +   # Add top two items
     {  # Sort top of the stack
        # Implicitly print top of the stack
```

This also works with a **0 byte** program.

Comment: @Adnan [Three days ago](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/1c339310d567fce64b307344cf08d396ac71b4ae), actually. Still, well played...

Comment: @Doorknob Just in time haha

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by eliminating your source code.

Comment: You can also shorten `05AB1E` by first eliminating the leading zero, and then omitting the `1`, as `1E==E`. Then you get just `5ABE`, -2 bytes.

Comment: @Dennis great observation

Comment: Does this language do the problem by default or something?

Comment: @djechlin yes. This language can, without any code, solve this exact problem.. >.> (line 2059: https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/commit/1c339310d567fce64b307344cf08d396ac71b4ae)

Comment: is @justaprogrammer actually Adnan in disguise?

Comment: I think he saw that in the sandbox and added the thing

Comment: @Dennis this reminds me of Stuck printing “Hello, world!” without any input. That is an amazing observation.

Comment: [5 bytes lol](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fxe1wk3b1//9mAA "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Comment: I challenge you with this question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/240385/invent-new-programming-language-and-write-hello-world-in-it :)

Answer (score 9):

### Pyth, <s>17</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
uS`+vGv_GQ\1
```

```
u        Q\1    reduce range(input()) on base case of "1" (string)
   +vG          eval the string (to get a number), and add...
      v_G       the same number, reversed first and then eval'd
 S`             convert back to string and sort
```

[Try it on the online interpreter](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=uS%60%2BvGv_GQ%5C1&input=7&debug=0).

Comment: What is this magic? How does this work?

Comment: @justaprogrammer I've added an explanation. :)

Comment: Huh, but how. How do you test this code?

Comment: @justaprogrammer I've added a link to an online interpreter that you can run the code on.

Comment: This is awesome, it is so short, yet so beautiful

Answer (score 8):

### CJam, 15 bytes

```
1ri{_sW%i+s$i}*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1ri%7B_sW%25i%2Bs%24i%7D*&input=10)

#### Explanation

```
1     e# Push 1 as the start of the sequence.
ri    e# Read input and convert to integer N.
{     e# Run this block N times...
  _s  e#   Duplicate and convert to string.
  W%  e#   Reverse string.
  i+  e#   Convert back to integer and add to previous value.
  s$  e#   Convert to string and sort.
  i   e#   Convert back to integer for the next iteration.
}*
```

Comment: how can all these languages be so short

Comment: @justaprogrammer Single-character names for built-in functions help. ;) CJam, Pyth and Brachylog are all golfing languages, specifically designed with code golf in mind. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf#Dedicated_golfing_languages.) Then there's also languages like APL and J that aren't golfing languages at all but are similarly terse, because the designers thought it would be a good idea.

Comment: Which one do you recommend the most for winning challenges like these?

Comment: @justaprogrammer I wouldn't pick one based on which one is winning these challenges (that would likely be Pyth or Jelly). It can be just as fun to golf in a "normal" language (especially because there might be more competition *within* that language). For a golfing language, it's probably more important that you enjoy using it. CJam is quite fun - it's a stack-based which makes you bend your mind a bit more than other languages, and at the same time it's quite a powerful language, that I've started to use for simple throwaway scripts outside of golf, which is a good boost to my productivity.

Comment: These languages look very interesting and I can't wait to learn one myself. I don't know what jelly is? Is that some kind of gelatine or something?

Comment: @justaprogrammer Jelly is [Dennis's](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) language: https://github.com/DennisMitchell/Jelly ... I think documentation is still pretty sparse for it though (and the language is under active development).

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, 70 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @user81655*

```
f=n=>n?+[...+[...''+(b=f(n-1))].reverse().join``+b+''].sort().join``:1
```

*sigh* JavaScript is really verbose. A **lot** (> 50%) of the code is just case to string + array function + join + cast to int. I've tried reduce, eval, and all sorts of stuff but this seems to be the shortest.

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3Dn%3D%3En%3F%2B%5B...''%2B((b%3Df(n-1))%2B%20%2B%5B...''%2Bb%5D.reverse().join%60%60)%5D.sort().join%60%60%3A1%0A%0Af(7)) (All browsers work)

Comment: Just like mine, but better (and posted earlier). Bah!

Comment: String Manipulation is JS is *so* long, you have my condolences

Comment: @user81655 cool, thanks! I would of never thought to re-order that way

Comment: ```f=n=>n?[...+[...b=f(n-1)].reverse().join``+b+''].sort().join``:'1'``` if returning string allowed

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 72

```
f=lambda x,n=1:x and f(x-1,int(''.join(sorted(`n+int(`n`[::-1])`))))or n
```

Recursive function, makes use of the Python 2 shorthand for `__repr__`, which will break once the function reaches very large values (an `L` will be appended to the number's string), I'm not certain from the spec if there is a place where we can stop, but if not changing to `str()` only adds 6 bytes, but then it becomes slightly shorter to output as a string, at 75 bytes:

```
f=lambda x,n='1':x and f(x-1,''.join(sorted(str(int(n)+int(n[::-1])))))or n
```

1 byte saved thanks to trichoplax on this version

Comment: Is that a surplus space before the `or` in the second code block?

Comment: @trichoplax thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
0,1 .|-1=:0&Rr+R=o.
```

#### Explanation

```
0,1 .               § If Input is 0, unify the Output with 1
     |              § Else
      -1=:0&R       § unify R with the output of this main predicate, with input = Input - 1
             r+R=o. § Reverse R, add it to itself and order it, then unify with the Output.
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 67 bytes

```
import Data.List
g i=i:g(sort$show$read i+read(reverse i))
(g"1"!!)
```

Usage example: `(g"1"!!) 7`-> `"668"`.

It's a direct implementation of the definition: starting with `"1"`, repeatedly append the reverse-add-sort result of the current element. The main function `(g"1"!!)` picks the `i`th element.

Comment: This is the most readable program under 70 bytes!

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 77 bytes

```
n->(x=1;for _=1:n x=(p=parse)(join(sort(["$(x+p(reverse("$x")))"...])))end;x)
```

This is a lambda function that accepts an integer and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(n::Int)
    # Begin x at 1
    x = 1

    # Repeat this process n times
    for _ = 1:n
        # Add x to itself with reversed digits
        s = x + parse(reverse("$x"))

        # Refine x as this number with the digits sorted
        x = parse(join(sort(["$s"...])))
    end

    # Return x after the process (will be 1 if n was 0)
    return x
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## Jelly, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

I'm sure this can probably be golfed, as this is my first answer in Jelly/in a tacit language.

```
DUḌ+ðDṢḌ Performs RATS
1Ç¡      Loops

D        Converts integer to decimal
 U       Reverses
  Ḍ      Converts back to integer
   +     Adds original and reversed
    ð    Starts new chain
     D   Converts back to decimal
      Ṣ  Sorts
       Ḍ Back to integer again

1        Uses 1 instead of input
 Ḍ       Uses line above
  ¡      For loop
```

EDIT: Saved 1 byte, thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 40 bytes

```perl6
{(1,{[~] ($_+.flip).comb.sort}...*)[$_]} # 40
```

( If you want it to return an Int put a `+` right before `[~]` )

#### Usage:

```perl6
# give it a lexical name
my &RATS = {…}

say RATS 5; # 77

# This implementation also accepts a list of indexes

# the first 10 of the sequence
say RATS ^10; # (1 2 4 8 16 77 145 668 1345 6677)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, <s>179</s> 156 Bytes

<s>I can't see how I could golf it more, but I'm sure there's a way.</s> Thanks to @LeakyNun I took the time to come down on this and golf it the proper way, I could maybe still win some bytes by using another approach.

```lua
k=0z=table
for i=0,io.read()do
t={}(""..k+(""..k):reverse()):gsub("%d",function(d)t[#t+1]=d
end)z.sort(t)k=k<1 and 1or tonumber(z.concat(t,""))
end
print(k)
```

#### Ungolfed and explanations

```lua
k=0                                  
z=table                              -- z is a pointer on the table named table
                                     -- it allows me to use its functions
                                     -- while saving 4 bytes/use

for i=0,io.read()                    -- Iterate n times for the nth element
do
  t={}
  (""..a+(""..a):reverse())          -- we add k with its "reversed" value
                                     -- and convert the whole thing to a string
    :gsub(".",function(d)            -- for each character in it, use an anonymous fucntion
       t[#t+1]=d end)                -- which insert them in the array t
  z.sort(t)                          
  a=a<1 and 1 or                     -- if i==0, k=1
     tonumber(z.concat(t,""))        -- else we concat t in a string and convert it to number
end
print(k)
```

Comment: Well it looks like you aren't here anymore... but maybe you can refer to my java answer.

Comment: @LeakyNun Well, I'm not participating a lot this times but still peaking at challenges from time to times, I'll try to take a look at your answer, but even without that I see some thing that can be golfed pretty easily (`a=a<1 and 1or` for instance).

Comment: we would be glad  – I would be glad  – to have you back.

Answer (score 3):

### Java 1.8, 251 bytes

```java
interface R{static void main(String[]a){int i,r,n=1,c=0,t=Byte.valueOf(a[0]);while(++c<=t){i=n;for(r=0;i!=0;i/=10){r=r*10+i%10;}n+=r;a[0]=n+"";char[]f=a[0].toCharArray();java.util.Arrays.sort(f);n=Integer.valueOf(new String(f));}System.out.print(n);}}
```

#### Expanded

```java
interface R{
static void main(String[]args){
    int input,reversed,nextValue=1,count=0,target=Byte.valueOf(args[0]);
    while(++count<=target){
        input=nextValue;
        for(reversed=0;input!=0;input/=10){reversed=reversed*10+input%10;}
        nextValue+=reversed;
        args[0]=nextValue+"";
        char[]sortMe=args[0].toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(sortMe);
        nextValue=Integer.valueOf(new String(sortMe));
    }
    System.out.print(nextValue);
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `interface` R instead of `class` R which is 4 bytes shorter?

Comment: @WillSherwood because you can then omit the public modifier on main(), making it shorter overall :)

Answer (score 3):

### Seriously, 17 bytes

```
1,`;$R≈+$S≈`n
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=MSxgOyRS4omIKyRT4omIYG4&input=NQ)

Explanation:

```
1,`;$R≈+$S≈`n
1              push 1
 ,`       `n   do the following n times:
   ;$R≈        reverse
       +       add
        $S≈    sort
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>70</s> 66 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,a=1:n<1or int(''.join(sorted(`f(n-1)+f(n-1,-1)`))[::a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBDoIwEEX3nmLChplYiGXZiBcxJIyBQolMSe3GEM5eqqv/Fu/97RtnL01Ktn3z@hoYRHGrjdy1D@AkYlnWi3eCHx/iOGBvUSpN1/@oTD3R0xjuKNlfkRsILNOI@kbmAlvIJ1DsB1QP2I@iztbKEZ0Ci44onQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) 2, 11 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
;1{↔;?+o}ⁱ⁽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@29tWP2obYq1vXZ@7aPGjY8a9/7/b/4/CgA)

### Explanation

```
;1{↔;?+o}ⁱ⁽
  {     }ⁱ  Repeatedly apply the following,
 1            starting at 1,
;         ⁽   a number of times equal to the input:
   ↔            reverse,
    ;?+         add the original input,
       o        then sort the resulting number
```

I'm not quite clear on what this does with zero digits, but the question doesn't state any particular handling, and they probably don't appear in the sequence anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
!¡ödOdS+↔1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X/HQwsPbUvxTgrUftU0x/P//vwUA)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 79 bytes

```
n=>eval("r=1;while(n--)r=+[...+[...r+''].reverse().join``+r+''].sort().join``")
```

82 bytes without `eval`:

```
n=>[...Array(n)].reduce(r=>+[...+[...r+''].reverse().join``+r+''].sort().join``,1)
```

All those conversions are painful.

@edc65 I actually saved 4 bytes by switching from `map` to `reduce` this time... no doubt you'll prove me wrong again though.

Comment: `for` is shorter: `n=>eval("for(r=1;n--)r=+[...+[...r+''].reverse().join\`\`+r+''].sort().join\`\`")`

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Doesn't work for `n=0`, even after I've fixed the syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 91 Bytes

Input as Integer, result is printed to the screen.

```
def f(n):
 t=1
 for i in range(n):t=int("".join(sorted(str(int(str(t)[::-1])+t))))
 print t
```

This could be a lot shorter with some recursion magic I guess, but I cant wrap my head around it yet. Gonna have a fresh look later and hopefully improve this one.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 83 bytes

```
def f(n):
 v='1'
 for _ in v*n:v=''.join(sorted(str(int(v)+int(v[::-1]))))
 print v
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 10.3, <s>66</s> 61 bytes

```
Nest[FromDigits@Sort@IntegerDigits[#+IntegerReverse@#]&,1,#]&
```

Quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>171</s> <s>167</s> <s>163</s> 160 bytes

```java
int f(int n){int a=n>0?f(n-1):0,x=10,b[]=new int[x],c=a,d=0;for(;c>0;c/=x)d=d*x+c%x;for(a+=d;a>0;a/=x)b[a%x]++;for(;a<x;c=b[a++]-->0?c*x+--a:c);return n>0?c:1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#JZDPioMwEMbP61OEQiHZGFdPBdPYJ9hTj5LDGLUEbBSN2yzis7uT7WU@mG/@/GamtRmsIWaAZSHfYN12WOdJT2N0bIsCylX5radOFKzM06CKPG1qrVz3IujXQadGQdqqXPbjTKWpcmm@VGCtaj8DN@fwnweuWgnoQfSaGs5Bc/5ugWuQRmGOcy0EbjPYKASUhsm58@vsSGQwZSH3Y3ozLx48ys9oW/JEcnr3s3WPWsP8WNiWfMTJkd8imL2qi7ScM3L/XXz3zMbVZxPW@8FRy0@kIiceD4o/oCzDBzAmkz3Zjz8)

Not the longest entry! \o/

Comment: @Katenkyo see [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70692/48934)

Comment: It is ok f(1)...f(20) But from f(21) result seems wrong...

Comment: Loss of precision I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 102 Bytes

```php
$r=[1];$i++<$argn;sort($v),$r[]=join($v))$v=str_split(bcadd(strrev($e=end($r)),$e));echo$r[$argn];
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ce999f7aa824bbe12ccfe4421222922a3f64698)

### PHP, 95 Bytes

n <= 39

```php
for($r=[1];$i++<$argn;sort($v),$r[]=join($v))$v=str_split(strrev($e=end($r))+$e);echo$r[$argn];
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 20 bytes

```
{x{.o@<o:$x+.|$x}/1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82quqJaL9/BJt9KpUJbr0alolbfsPZ/mrqixX8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```scala
Stream.iterate("1"){p=>p.toInt+p.reverse.toInt+""sorted}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcwxCsMgFAbgPaf4cVIKkhzAQMcOnXoCa57Ukj5FHyEQcnbboeO3fC341ff8fFMQ3H1i0C7ES8O1FBwDsPkVEQ79IZX8xyah6oW0mpQ5ipuLlXxjuRRbaaPa6G@lWq5Cy9kBPUIyptHYmH9JeGmGm1FqYllZR83GmOHsXw)

An infinite stream.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 9 bytes

```
=1:sZ+\rZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39bQqjhKO6Yo6v9/AA)

1-indexed.

### Explanation

```
=1            first term is 1
  :           sequence mode
              each term equals
   s                           sort(                                   )
    Z                                previous
     +                                        plus
      \r                                           reverse(          )
        Z                                                   previous
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>91</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 76 bytes

```powershell
$ofs=''
for($c="1";$args[0]--){$c="$("$(+$c+"$($c[20..0])")"|% t*y|sort)"}$c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvNCoMwEATgu08hYVtNJRK1f1LyJOKhLIk9CCkboRT12VO7wvANDMzbfyyFlx1HhZ5sBGfmCN4Fk2WJ85QDGlGJBzxpCJ3ulZLzf4J8SwFYbAXY1bosdS@FFMshnU7fJXiapFgB45ocwaWardiabdgze2Gv7I29s@3@2s9NG38)

PowerShell converts strings to `long` by default. The maximum length would always be 19 chars.

Cool challenge!
-2 bytes thanks to Mazzy!

Comment: `for` is shorter in the Powershell. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HchNCsMgFATgvadI5LWJDUpMf6F4g94gZFFEk0WoRYVSkpzd2gcz38C83cf4MJl55tp5k8CqJYGzQVUVsc7XoBWV9F6W8PRj6NuBc7b8T6hzGtBNHtB9rniY1xgnLpkQ7cAoo@uuiIfvGpyPjG6g00bIHmzRohLt0CN6Qs/oBb2it/QD "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
1?(ms
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=1?(ms&inputs=7&header=&footer=)

### Explained

```
1?(ms

1?          # Push 1 followed by the input
  (         # for n in range(0, input):
    m       #   push tos + tos[::-1] (palindromize on integers doesn't make it a palindrome)
     +s     #   add and sort the result
```

It's a shame how in order to remain competitive, one has to port other answers. Why do I say this? Because I have a nifty 21 byte function that accomplishes the same task:

```
@f:1|0=[1|n⨪@f;:ŉ+]s;
```

Example usage:

```
6 @f; , # Single number
0 11 r °f; z # Provide a test case unit kinda display
```

Comment: what does `ŉ` do?

Comment: @Razetime it [reverses the top of the stack](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal/blob/89d9540c4a1bf4fd9c8da82df1ea5fda33042341/docs/reference.txt#L172)

Comment: would `m` work instead of `:ŉ` ?

Comment: @Razetime no, because it pushes `a + reversed(a)` not `a, reversed(a)`

Comment: I meant `1?(ms`, it says TODO is not defined

Comment: @Razetime `a + a[::-1]` != `[a, a[::-1]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116081/discussion-between-lyxal-and-razetime).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 51 bytes

```perl
$.=join'',sort(($.+reverse$.)=~/./g)while$_--;say$.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FzzYrPzNPXV2nOL@oRENDRU@7KLUstag4VUVP07ZOX08/XbM8IzMnVSVeV9e6OLFSRe//f/N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usm5gAA)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FzzYrPzNPXV2nOL@oRKG4ICezBMhR0dMuSi1LLSpOVdErz8jMSVWJ19W1Lk6sVNH7/9/8X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDg/@6iQA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 146 bytes

```
c(r:String):NNI==reduce(+,[(ord(r.i)-48)*10^(#r-i) for i in 1..#r]);f(n:INT):NNI==(n<1=>1;v:=f(n-1);v:=v+c(reverse(v::String));c(sort(v::String)))
```

test and results [RATS sequence]

```
(3) -> [[i, f(i)] for i in 0..20]
   (3)
   [[0,1], [1,2], [2,4], [3,8], [4,16], [5,77], [6,145], [7,668], [8,1345],
    [9,6677], [10,13444], [11,55778], [12,133345], [13,666677], [14,1333444],
    [15,5567777], [16,12333445], [17,66666677], [18,133333444], [19,556667777],
    [20,1233334444]]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 91 bytes

```
proc R n {join [lsort [split [expr {$n?[set v [R [expr $n-1]]]+[string rev $v]:1}] ""]] ""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYwxCgMhEEX7PcVnsQuBtd0md9jWTCUSJphRdCKBxbObCGn@gwfvq49j5JI8DgjOZ2KBizUVhas58g/hkwtOIzdXg6LBHX9n5GqJ6OKqFpYHSmgwjXbbCetKc/qYDWNblF8BZ35rheH9Pl8M08LiC7jDbuML)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

1-indexed.

```
_+ìw)ìñ}g
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Xyvsdyns8X1n&input=OA)

```
_+ìw)ìñ}g     :Implicit input of integer U
_             :Function taking an integer Z as input
 +            :  Add
  ì           :    Convert Z to digit array
   w          :   Reverse and convert back
    )         :  End add
     ì        :  Convert result to digit array
      ñ       :  Sort and convert back
       }      :End function
        g     :Starting with 1, do that U times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [<s>13</s> 8 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

Ignore that it was previously 13 bytes, I never realized sorting doesn't cast back to strings when needed, so I fixed that.

```
'▀ƒʠBÀ½Ó
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Ji57Oj4rLjx9MQ==&input=MAoxCjIKMwo0CjUKNgo3&flags=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `&.{:>+.<}1`

```
&.            Mutate X N times via block B
  {           B has key of `_`
    :>        Sort ascending
        _     Implied
      +       Plus
          _   Implied
        .<    Reversed
  }           End block
1             and X is the number one
_             and N is STDIN; implied
```